# How to match string values from text file in bash script

Tags: arrays, string, bash, file

I am trying to read and display each word in a text file and then highlight a specified vowel or consonant.

When I read from the file I can only read an entire line so I used a loop to read each word in the line. However when I do this I'm not able to access different positions in that word. (e.g. if the word is "happy" I cannot access the 2nd positon for the letter "a")

```
#READS EACH LINE
while read line
    do
            #READS EACH WORD IN THE LINE
            for word in $line
            do
                    #LOOPS THROUGH EACH CHARACTER IN THE WORD
                    for (( i=0; i<${#word}; i++ ))
                    do
                            #LOOPS THROUGH ALL VALUES IN VOWEL ARRAY
                            for (( j=0; j<10; j++ ))
                            do
                                    #MATCHES IF A VOWEL IS FOUND
                                    if [ "${word[$i]}" == "${varray[$j]}" ]
                                    then
                                            let vcount++
                                            echo i:$i  j:$j
                                            echo word: ${word[$i]} varray: ${varray[$j]}    #DEBUG

                                    fi
                            done
                    done
                                            #MORE CODE HERE DOING STUFF PRINTING TO SCREEN
            done
    done < $file
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?
or should I go about reading the file a different way in order to access each character of the word?

When I `echo` the word in the double `for loop` it displays the entire word as the first position instead of just the first character. And the rest of the positions 2, 3, etc are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing array indexing with taking the substring of a string ("substringing", if you will). Those are completely distinct operations in every programming language I'm familiar with. In bash, array indexing is done with the `${arr[index]}` form of variable substitution. What you need is the `${str:index:length}` form of variable substitution, which does substringing. Here's how it can be used to make your script work:

```
#!/bin/bash

file='file';
varray='aeiouy';

#READS EACH LINE
while read line; do
    #READS EACH WORD IN THE LINE
    for word in $line; do
        #LOOPS THROUGH EACH CHARACTER IN THE WORD
        for (( i=0; i<${#word}; i++ )); do
            #LOOPS THROUGH ALL VALUES IN VOWEL ARRAY
            for (( j=0; j<${#varray}; j++ )); do
                #MATCHES IF A VOWEL IS FOUND
                wordChar="${word:$i:1}";
                vChar="${varray:$j:1}";
                if [[ "$wordChar" == "$vChar" ]]; then
                    let vcount++;
                    echo "i:$i  j:$j";
                    echo "wordChar: $wordChar vChar: $vChar";
                fi;
            done;
        done;
    done;
    #MORE CODE HERE DOING STUFF PRINTING TO SCREEN
done <$file;

exit 0;
```

Demo:

```
cat file;
## abc def ghi
## jkl mno pqr

./script;
## i:0  j:0
## wordChar: a vChar: a
## i:1  j:1
## wordChar: e vChar: e
## i:2  j:2
## wordChar: i vChar: i
## i:2  j:3
## wordChar: o vChar: o
```

Other notes:

- Your code to read from the file and break it up into words is just fine. The only caveat is that the `read line` command will lose leading and trailing whitespace. This is not important for your script, but if you wanted to solve this, you could just call `read` by itself, and the entire line (including leading and trailing whitespace) would be read into the `$REPLY` variable by default.
- In your code, you iterated `j` from 0 to 9, but the max depends on the length of `varray` (which is actually a string; should probably rename that), so you should use `${#varray}` as the max.
- Use `[[ ... ]]` for expression evaluation instead of the old `[ ... ]` form; the newer form is slightly more powerful.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it clarified things a bit more for me. I managed to get my script to match the vowels :D. Now when I add IF statements with different conditions depending on the number of vowels it always enters the same IF statement regardless if there is 1, 2 or no vowels?